# How to create object/singleton of generic type in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, singleton

In the code shown below, how can I convert `EmptyTree` to object (Singleton) ?

```
trait Tree[T] {
    def contains(num: T): Boolean
    def inc( num: T ): Tree[T]
  }


class EmptyTree[T <% Ordered[T] ] extends Tree[T] {
    def contains(num:T):Boolean = false
    def inc(num:T):Tree[T] = {
        new DataTree(num, new EmptyTree, new EmptyTree)
    }
    override def toString = "."
}

class DataTree[T <% Ordered[T] ](val x:T, val left:Tree[T], val right:Tree[T]) extends Tree[T] {

    def contains(num:T):Boolean = {
        if( num < x ) left.contains(x)
        else if ( num > x ) right.contains(x)
        else true
    }
    def inc(num:T):Tree[T] = {
        if(num < x ) new DataTree(x, left.inc(num), right)
        else if ( num > x ) new DataTree(x, left, right.inc(num))
        else this
    }
    override def toString = "{" + left + x + right + "}"
}


val t = new DataTree(20, new EmptyTree[Int], new EmptyTree[Int])
                                                //> t  : greeting.Test.DataTree[Int] = {.20.}
val p = t.inc(10)                               //> p  : greeting.Test.Tree[Int] = {{.10.}20.}
val a = p.inc(30)                               //> a  : greeting.Test.Tree[Int] = {{.10.}20{.30.}}
val s = a.inc(5)                                //> s  : greeting.Test.Tree[Int] = {{{.5.}10.}20{.30.}}
val m = s.inc(11)                               //> m  : greeting.Test.Tree[Int] = {{{.5.}10{.11.}}20{.30.}}
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with templates? Are you using some kind of template preprocessor to generate the code? In Scala, the only use of "template" I know of is as a hypernym for "class" and "trait".

Comment: Scala Generics and C++ Templates are very different. Plus, template already has a well-defined meaning in Scala, which has nothing to do with generics. Also, the tag wiki for [tag:template] clearly says that applies only to either C++ or templating engines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me detalize Alexey's answer. Here is full implementation with some code style improvements:

First define your trait with aknowledgment of its covariance:

```
 trait Tree[+T] {
    def contains[U >: T : Ordering](num: U): Boolean

    def inc[U >: T : Ordering](num: U): Tree[U]
  }
```

Next define your subtype-of-all-trees object

```
  case object EmptyTree extends Tree[Nothing] {
    def contains[U >: Nothing : Ordering](num: U): Boolean = false
    def inc[U >: Nothing : Ordering](num: U): Tree[U] =
      DataTree(num, EmptyTree, EmptyTree)
    override def toString = "."
  }
```

Now change your general case implementation:

```
  case class DataTree[T: Ordering](x: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T] {
    import Ordering.Implicits._
    def contains[U >: T : Ordering](num: U): Boolean = 
      if (num < x) left.contains(x)
      else if (num > x) right.contains(x)
      else true

    def inc[U >: T : Ordering](num: U): Tree[U] = 
      if (num < x) DataTree(x, left.inc(num), right)
      else if (num > x) DataTree(x, left, right.inc(num))
      else this

    override def toString = "{" + left + x + right + "}"
  }
```

You could be a little bit frustrated since I replaced your `Ordered` with `Ordering`, but you should know that [view bounds are deprecated](http://jatinpuri.com/2014/03/replace-view-bounds/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Can you please help, Which book explains  generics in Scala?

Comment: @SunnyShah the first one at [official books list](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/books.html) - [in this chapter](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's much more clear than what I was trying to write

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix the generic argument because that's the only time you can provide it:

```
scala> trait A[T]
defined trait A

scala> object B extends A[Int]
defined object B
```

Obviously you want to reuse `EmptyTree` for all types of `T`, so instead of defining `A[SOMETYPE]` for each type just use bottom type `Nothing`:

```
scala> object B extends A[Nothing]
defined object B
```

This object can be used with any tree.

That's exactly how `Option[T]` is implemented in Scala. Here is how `None` is defined:

```
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `DataTree` is not covariant in `T`.

Comment: I tried what you said, Here is an error I am getting. http://pastebin.com/GqBpJ81v

Comment: @JörgWMittag true, it's invariant. I don't see it as a problem unless he wants to allow subclasses as tree values. Then define it as `trait tree[+T]`, it will work as well.

Comment: Well, if you just implement your solution, compilation of the OP's code fails with a variance error, that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

If keeping generics, also there is an option to add empty factory - like it's done for Map and Vector. Off course, with such an implementation it will not be a unique instance object for every creation, but when using `inc` method, it will not produce new objects, it will just reference itself.

```
object DataTree {
  def empty[T <% Ordered[T]] = new Tree[T] {
      def contains(num: T):Boolean = false
      def inc(num: T): Tree[T] = {
        new DataTree(num, this, this)
      }
      override def toString = "."
  }
}
```

So you can instantiate it as following:

```
val t = new DataTree(20, DataTree.empty[Int], DataTree.empty[Int])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Isn't is possible to have only one EmptyTree object?