# Working with covariant immutable collections in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, covariance

I am trying to create a function that applies to any collection that has `take`, `slice` and `drop`. That is, I would like to create a function that works on `IndexedSeq[Boolean]` and `Vector[Boolean]`, returning the same kind of object. This is what I have attempted after looking at this [How to create object/singleton of generic type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705623/how-to-create-object-singleton-of-generic-type-in-scala)

> and trying to use `IndexedSeqLike` instead of `Ordering`, to no avail

```
trait MutateLike[+T,-Y] {
  def apply[U >: T, Y](eo: U): Y
}

case object Mutate extends MutateLike[IndexedSeq[Boolean],IndexedSeq[Boolean]]{
  def apply[U >: IndexedSeq[Boolean],IndexedSeq[Boolean]]( eo : U ): IndexedSeq[Boolean] = {
    val point = (eo.length * scala.util.Random.nextDouble).toInt
    eo.take( point - 1 ) ++ eo.slice( point-1,point ).map(!_) ++ eo.drop( point )
  }  
}
```

After trying many other things. However, it does not work and yields errors  to the tune of `value length is not a member of type parameter U`. But U is covariant with T, which in this case is IndexedSeq, right? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `U` is a supertype of `IndexSeq` so you cannot do any assumption on the members it has or not

Comment: BTW, aren't you hiding the `Y` defined on `MutateLike` in you `apply` method ?

Comment: @Dici no, it's returning it.

Comment: Nope because your method takes a type parameter `Y` which is not the same as the `Y` that parametrizes `MutateLike`. You are hiding it

Comment: Sorry, you lost me here. Do you mean that the Y in the first line is not the same as the Y in the second line?

Comment: Yes. It's like if you had a member name `y` and a local variable of the same name in a method. The `y` identifier would then refer to the local variable in the relevant scope and to the class attribute otherwise. You signature should probably have been something like `apply[U >: T, X <: Y](eo: U): X` but it does not fix your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making your life much more complicated than it needs to be. Try this

```
case object Mutate{
  def apply( eo : IndexedSeq[Boolean] ): IndexedSeq[Boolean] = {
    val point = (eo.length * scala.util.Random.nextDouble).toInt
    eo.take( point - 1 ) ++ eo.slice( point-1,point ).map(!_) ++ eo.drop( point )
  }  
}

scala> Mutate( IndexedSeq( true, false, false, true, false, false ) )
res8: IndexedSeq[Boolean] = Vector(false, false, false, true, false, false)

scala> Mutate( Vector( true, false, false, true, false, false ) )
res9: IndexedSeq[Boolean] = Vector(false, false, false, true, false, false)
```

This is just straight, old fashioned object-oriented polymorphism. A `Vector[Boolean]` IS A `IndexedSeq[Boolean]`, so it is substitutable for that.

With your declaration of `MutateLike` and its variances, you are making decisions about what sort of parameterizations of `MutateLike` are deemed to inherit from other parameters of `MutateLike`. But that's not what you are interested in expressing or trying to do.

(Of course there's no need to use an object declaration at all. You could have defined `mutate` as a simple function.)

Comment: Upvoted because it **Keep**s things **Stupid and Simple**. However, this is way less general, I'm not sure it's enough for the OP as we don't have all the context

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.SeqLike

def mutate[Repr, To](xs: SeqLike[Boolean, Repr], rng: Random)(implicit ev: CanBuildFrom[Repr, Boolean, To]) = {
  val builder = ev.apply()
  val iter = xs.iterator
  var i = rng.nextInt(xs.length)
  while (i > 0) { i -= 1; builder += iter.next }
  builder += !iter.next
  while (iter.hasNext) builder += iter.next
  builder.result
}
```

Now

```
val xs = Array(true, true, false, true, false)
mutate(xs, new scala.util.Random(111L))
```

results in

```
Array[Boolean] = Array(true, true, false, false, false)
```

and

```
val xs = Vector(true, true, false, true, false)
mutate(xs, new scala.util.Random(111L))
```

results in

```
scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Boolean] = Vector(true, true, false, false, false)
```

The `mutate` method can also be easily generalized to handle collections of types other than `Booleans` like so:

```
def mutate[Repr, To, A](xs: SeqLike[A, Repr], f: A => A, rng: Random)(implicit ev: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, To]) = {
  val builder = ev.apply()
  val iter = xs.iterator
  var i = rng.nextInt(xs.length)
  while (i > 0) { i -= 1; builder += iter.next }
  builder += f(iter.next)
  while (iter.hasNext) builder += iter.next
  builder.result
}
```

Then

```
Seq.iterate("I am what I am", 16){ s=> 
  mutate(s, (ch: Char) => (ch ^ 3).toChar, rng)
}.mkString("\n")
```

results in

```
I am what I am
J am what I am
I am what I am
J am what I am
J#am what I am
J#am what I bm
J#am what I#bm
J#am what#I#bm
J#am what#I bm
J#am whaw#I bm
J am whaw#I bm
J am what#I bm
J am what#I#bm
J am what#J#bm
I am what#J#bm
J am what#J#bm
```